# Loop through array and draw * when value is true

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array with values true and false. I want to check if a value of an array is true draw '*'. And each row should move 1 position left.

```
Expected result -> 
'*****
  *****
   *****
    *****
     *****'
```

I tried this way.

```
 let points = [
  [true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false],
  [false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true],
  [true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false],
  [false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true],
  [true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false]
];

let m = 10;
let n = 5;
let board = "";
let space = '\xa0';

for(let i = 0; i < points.length; ++i) {
  for(let j = 0; j < points[i].length; ++j) {
      if(points[i][j])  {
        for (let y = 0; y < points[i]; y++) {
          if(y > 0) {
            board += space + "*";
            space += space;
          }
          for (let x  = 0; x <  points[i][j]; x++) {
              board += "*";
          }
          board += "\n";
        }
      }
    return '';
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain the correlation between the array and your expected output in more detail? I don't see any spaces except at the beginning of the expected string

Comment: please add the wanted result (where are the O's?) and what goes wrong with your code.

Comment: I should have an array of * which will be created depends on arrays values. I will use the array later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a couple `reduce()` functions to print the outer and inner loop using the index to control the initial spaces. The outer `reduce` iterates over each row and the inner `reduce` makes the `*` strings based on the boolean values.

```js
let points = [
  [true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false],
  [false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true],
  [true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false],
  [false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true],
  [true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false]
];

let result = points.reduce((str, arr, i) => {
  return str 
         + ' '.repeat(i) 
         + arr.reduce((subst, bool) => subst + (bool ? '*' : ''), '') 
         + '\n'
}, '')
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
points
  .map((row, i) => " ".repeat(i) + row.map(cell => (cell ? "*" : " ")).join(""))
  .join("\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, and if you want to stick to loops, the loop should be similar to this.

```
let points = [
  [true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false],
  [false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true],
  [true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false],
  [false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true],
  [true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false]
];

let board = "";

for (let i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < points[i].length; j++) {
    if (j === 0 && i !== 0) {
      board += "<br>";
      for (let k = 0; k < i; k++) {
        board += "\xa0";
      }
    }
    board += points[i][j] ? "*" : " ";
  }
}

document.write(board);
```

However if you want the "expected result" that you showed, you need to remove the adding of spaces. Your expected result doesn't match the description in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). The code here is using contemporary ES6 for brevity but could easily be ported to ES5 if need be.

```
let points = [
    [true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false],
    [false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true],
    [true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false],
    [false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true],
    [true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false]
];

points.map((row, i) => {
    const padded = [];
    while (i--) {
        padded.push(' ');
    }
    return [
        ...padded,
        ...row.map(point => point ? '*' : ' ')
    ].join('');
}).join('\n');
```

I'm using:

- the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to *spread* the padded and points array items into a new array which is then just `join`ed into a string
- [arrow functions `() => {}`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) and an implicit `return` statement as the callback functions to `map`

**Outputs**

[image: Padded string]